# Unexpected results when multiplying window.innerHeight by a nonwhole number in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, unity-game-engine

Firstly, I'm by no means a web designer so I have very little idea what I'm doing.

I'm working on the HTML/Javascript for a Unity Webplayer application trying to make the Webplayer take up most (not all) of the browser's viewable area.  The `<body>` of the page is set to have no margins nor scroll bars like so,

```
<body margin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scroll="no">
```

I'm getting the values for the browser's viewable area like this,

```
winWidth = window.innerWidth;
winHeight = window.innerHeight;
```

And I call the Unity Webplayer with this,

```
unityObject.embedUnity("unityPlayer", "WebPlayer.unity3d", winWidth, winHeight, params);
```

Everything seems to work mostly properly with this setup.  However, when I multiply `winWidth` and `winHeight` by non-whole numbers (i.e., 0.5 or 1.9) the height is not properly scaled in Firefox 12.  Regardless of the value I put in there, it's always the same (wrong) vertical height.  In this picture, both `innerHeight` and `innerWidth` are multiplied by `0.9` and, as you can see, height is definitely wrong—and this is the wrong height I get no matter what non-whole number I multiply it by.
[image: innerHeight * 0.9]

This code works just fine in Chrome 19 and IE 9.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the exact situation is, as I'm not familiar with the Unity JavaScript interface you are using, but I think there's a good chance that you need to specify an integer width and height for the player, whereas your calculation is producing a non-integral number.

Simply write `Math.round(winWidth * 0.9)` instead of `winWidth * 0.9` to get the nearest integer result.

Comment: ...and that did it. I previously tried directly casting to an `int` and it didn't like that so I never looked for a `round` function. Thanks!!